# Cannot invoke method in secondary dex in Application's onCreate() method though I loaded the dex before

Tags: java, android, dalvik

I am using multidex solution in my project. I found several libs for multidex (https://github.com/casidiablo/multidex, https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin/pull/425). They are all based on modifying ClassLoader's pathList field by
reflect.

Every thing is OK. The Activity in secondary dex works well. But when I invoke method
in secondary dex in Application's onCreate() method ClassDefNotFound Exception will 
be got, though I loaded secondary dex before.

I am very sure the pathList is modified successfully. Using Class.forName(""), class in
secondary dex can be found.

Who knows why? Waiting for your answer. Thanks so much.

Call method in secondary dex like this,

```
public class CustomizedApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // load secondary dex here
    Dexter.loadAllDexes(this);

    super.onCreate();

    //invoke method in secondary dex
    ClassInSecondaryDex.foo();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert in JVM class loading but from my experience I know that all classes used in class (in normal way - not by reflection) should be known when class is initializing, I think it's faster than searching all the classes by class loader when they are invoked. So you have to use reflection in this situation but in your activities all classes will be loaded before activity initialization so it would work. When you use Class.forName() class loader search for class but it does not work like that in normal non-reflection code because it's really not efficient.

try this

```html
public class CustomizedApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // load secondary dex here
    Dexter.loadAllDexes(this);

    super.onCreate();

    //invoke method in secondary dex
    ClassInSecondaryDex.foo();
try{
    Class<?> clazz= Class.forName("your.package.ClassInSecondaryDex"); 
    clazz.getMethod("foo").invoke(clazz); 
}catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I like your answer. Maybe I should find a book about VM.

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't work because all classes used in class should be known before class initialization. You can use reflection to invoke method from secondary dex. So if want to invoke any other class in MyApplication you should add MyApplication to mainDexList and invoke other class using Class.forName("com.package.YourClass") and use reflection to create object and invoke method. You have to do this only in MyApplication class because you load other classes in it. If you invoke some simple class with couple of dependencies consider adding it with those dependencies to mainDexList

Comment: "pathList" field of ClassLoader is modified before ClassInSecondaryDex.foo() invoked. I thought at that time ClassLoader would try to find ClassInSecondaryDex in "pathList", and the class would be found. But It didn't work like that. I am really confused now. Could you help me out?